# Creating an overlay on UIButton image but only on the image itself

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, overlay

How to create a gray overlay view on a `UIButton` that contain an image, but to make the overlay to be shown only on the image itself, not on the whole button so just the image will be gray color.

Is it possible?

This is the button as it is:

[image: normal]

This is with overlay:

[image: overlay]

This is how I want it to be:

[image: final]

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused. Can you make up an image to show what you mean?

Comment: @woz I've added the images, please tell me if you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the image you want for the highlighted state. You can do this in a XIB or on your storyboard by setting the state to "Highlighted":

[image]

and then setting the image:

[image]

**OR**

Do it through code like this:

```
[theButton setImage:theImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

The image can be quickly duplicated and converted to black-and-white with Photoshop or GIMP, etc. Changing the image to black-and-white programmatically is way more work than it's worth.

Comment: I want the image in sometime at the application to be gray for the whole app runtime after the user do something. not only when the user click on it.

Comment: Oh in that case, set the image for the disabled state, `UIControlStateDisabled`, and use `theButton.enabled = NO;` when you want to disable it.

Comment: Actually I didn't checked it yet. just a moment.

Comment: you can still use the same approach and when you want it to be highlighted use the method [yourImageView setHighlighted:YES]